# I want to calculate 2 date fields

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have two fields I need to calculate. Control Procedure Testing Frequency "Auto Quarterly" and  Test Due Date value "3/30/22" I want the second value 3/30/22 show on another field Auto Quarterly Due date

If([Control Procedure Testing Frequency]=VALUEOF([Control Procedure Testing Frequency],"Auto-Quarterly"),([Test Due Date]=VALUEOF([Test Due Date],"3/30/22")))

Comment: I’m not following what you’re asking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.